# How to add attributes to all instances of a django form widget?

Tags: django, django-forms

So I am building Django forms using bootstrap, and I know that I can add attributes (such as class) my form using:

```
username = forms.CharField(max_length=24, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your desired username.'}))
```

But I am unable to find any way to apply a class attribute to ALL TextInput (or any other widget class). [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition) didn't help me, as it looks like it only allows you to set entire stylesheets and not just attributes.

I don't want to violate DRY, so how do I apply a certain attribute to all TextInput (or other widget) instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own CharField that implements your own widget_attrs method:

The original:

```
class CharField(Field, forms.CharField):
    widget = TextInput

    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        attrs = super(CharField, self).widget_attrs(widget)
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = {}
        if self.max_length is not None and isinstance(widget, (TextInput, HiddenInput)):
            # The HTML attribute is maxlength, not max_length.
            attrs.update({'maxlength': str(self.max_length)})
        return attrs
```

A suggestion:

```
class MyCharField(forms.CharField):
    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        attrs = super(MyCharField, self).widget_attrs(widget)
        attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Your desired username.'})
        if self.max_length is not None and isinstance(widget, (forms.TextInput, forms.HiddenInput)):
            # The HTML attribute is maxlength, not max_length.
            attrs.update({'maxlength': str(self.max_length)})
        return attrs
```

You could probably also leave out the if-clause for `max_length`, if you always specify one, but that's for you to try out.

Comment: Is there no way to override the actual CharField class, or is it just bad practice?

Comment: You mean CharField from `django.forms`?No … That's not your code. But you could have a formfields.py file and import it at your forms.py and would notice about nothing.

Comment: OK. Do I put this class in forms.py?

Comment: It depends on you where to put it. It needs to be available in forms.py, so putting it in forms.py would make it more easy, but also more cluttered.
You may also put it, as mentioned, in a seperate file.

This is getting into how python imports work though. And that's something that has been answered a lot of times on the web.

Answer (score 0):

simple way:

```
def set_attrs_for_fields(fields, default_attrs):
    for field_name in fields:
        field = fields[field_name]
        try:
            default_widget_attr = default_attrs[field.widget.__class__]
            for k, v in default_widget_attr.items():
                field.widget.attrs[k] = v
        except KeyError:
            pass

class MyForm(ProjFormBase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        set_attrs_for_fields(self.fields, self.get_default_attrs())

    def get_default_attrs(self):
        return {
                forms.TextInput: {'class': 'form-control'},
                forms.EmailInput: {'class': 'form-control'},
                forms.PasswordInput: {'class': 'form-control'},
            }
```

Alternatively you could use a custom filter check here: [Adding css classes to formfields in Django Templates](http://vanderwijk.info/blog/adding-css-classes-formfields-in-django-templates/)